# Dotnetnuke update displayname does not show immediately

Tags: dotnetnuke

In dnn in each of the skin i have placed a `<dnn:User` control. The app allows the user to update their display name (nothing but email).

when the user updates the email address and click update on page refresh it does not reflect on the skin. The new email does not show on the skin.

when i logout and login it shows correctly.

I am using DotnetNuke membership

After the UpdateUseris successfully called if i observe the clearcache is not clearing the current user info.

**if i see the httpcontext.Current.Items["UserInfo"] i can still see the old email etc.**

After i logout and login again i am able to see the new profile updated.

Is there any work around for this

how to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

The user will be cached - so make sure you use the API to update the display name.

```
                this.UserInfo.DisplayName = "New Name";
                UserController.UpdateUser(PortalId, this.UserInfo);
```